# How can I use Unstable repositories and install only packages in Testing by default (via AptConf)?

Tags: debian

I've followed the instructions on [debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/apt.html](https://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/apt.html#idm140485877996080) (and [the page linked there](https://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/sect.apt-get.html#sect.apt-upgrade)) which basically say to put the following text in `/etc/apt/sources.list`

```
# Unstable
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian unstable main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian unstable main contrib non-free

# Testing
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian testing main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian testing main contrib non-free

# Stable
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian stable main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian stable main contrib non-free

# Security updates
deb http://security.debian.org/ stable/updates main contrib non-free
deb http://security.debian.org/ testing/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ stable/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ testing/updates main contrib non-free
```

Then add `APT::Default-Release "testing";` to `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/local` to download only the packages in Testing.
Well, it didn't work.
I also tried adding `APT::Default-Release "testing";` to `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/70debconf` as suggested at https://wiki.debian.org/AptConf but `apt dist-upgrade` still wanted to install Unstable's pakages.

Comment: is it installing all packages from unstable or just some?  if you've already installed unstable packages later than what's in testing, `apt-get` won't downgrade anything.  and if you have already installed a newer version of a package (e.g. a library) from unstable than what is available in testing, then `apt-get` will only install dependent packages from testing if they don't conflict with the installed (unstable) version of the package.

Comment: eventually (in around two weeks) testing will have caught up to unstable for most packages, so this issue will mostly go away.    BTW, always test an upgrade or install by using `apt-get`'s `-d -u` or `-V -d -u` options.  e.g. `apt-get -d -u install pkg` or `apt-get -V -d -u dist-upgrade`.  Remove those options when you're sure it's going to install what you want.

Comment: @cas I ran `apt list --upgradable` after an `apt update`, for every package I got `packagename/unstable,testing version ...`. The versions were actually those of packages in Sid.

Comment: Please supply the output of `apt-cache policy` and `apt-cache policy PACKAGE` where `PACKAGE` is the name of a package that you'd expect a different candidate version of.

Comment: @FerencWágner see my answer. Thanks for the interest :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went through a bit of documentation and I found a solution in the Debian administration handbook, [section 2.7.6](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch02.en.html#_tracking_literal_testing_literal_with_some_packages_from_literal_unstable_literal):
I have both Testing and Unstable repos in my `/etc/apt/sources.list` and I have created `/etc/apt/preferences` with

```
Package: *
Pin: release a=unstable
Pin-Priority: 100
```

in it. Running `apt-cache policy gnome-shell` (I use `gnome-shell` as a tell-tale since different versions are available in Unstable and Testing, respectively 3.20 and 3.18) now correctly displays both 3.20 and 3.18 as available versions and the latter as the candidate.

The documentation I've found most useful:
https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch02.en.html
[man apt_preferences](https://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?sektion=5&query=apt_preferences&apropos=0&manpath=sid&locale=en)

Comment: I still have a couple of doubts, though:

1) The system should run the same way even if I set priority P for unstable so that 100 <= P < 500, right?

2) Say I install a package from Unstable, then I shut down my system and fire it up again 2 months later. By that time in Testing there would be a newer version than the one I got from Unstable. Apt should then track the version in Testing (because it's both higher priority and newer version), right?

Comment: You're correct on both counts.

Answer (score 2):

To install a specific package from Testing you can do:

```
apt-get install pckg_name/testing
```

or

```
apt-get -t testing install pckg_name
```

Also you can build the package by yourself, first you need to need to install
`apt-listbugs` , `debhelper`, `devscripts`, and `build-essential`

```
apt-get update
apt-get build-dep pckg_name
apt-get -b source pckg_name
dpkg -i pckg_name
```

Create a new file `/etc/apt/preferences.d/testing` and set the priority `900`, `apt` will know the testing package have a higher priority.

```
Package: *
Pin: release a=testing
Pin-Priority: 900
```

then update

Comment: Thanks. Anyway, I know that, what I want is Debian not installing Unstable packages when doing a `dist-upgrade`.